# MLE of a certain probablity

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,X_2, \dots ,X_n$ be a random sample from the pdf

$$f(x,\gamma)=\frac{2\gamma+1}{2\gamma}x^{\frac{1}{2\gamma}},\quad 0\leq x \leq 1,\gamma>0,$$
what are the steps to find the **Maximum Likelihood Estimator** of the probability $P(X\leq 0.5)$?

All I can think of is integrating the pdf from $0$ to $0.5$, but then there'll be no $x_i$ and the likelihood function would be
$$L(\gamma)=n\int_0^{0.5}f(x,\gamma)\,dx$$
Is the solution of the equation 
$$\frac{dL(\gamma)}{d\gamma}=0$$
the final answer?

Comment: As $P(X_1\le 1/2)=g(\gamma)$ for some function $g$,  the required MLE is $g(\hat \gamma)$ where $\hat \gamma$ is the MLE of $\gamma$ found using usual means. So only invariance property of MLE is required.